# Xamarin iOS App crashing after users upgrade to iOS 13

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash, ios13

After users upgrade their devices to iOS 13 our Xamarin iOS app opens and immediately crashes, but if the users then completely uninstall and then install the app it works perfectly fine.
We use AppCenter to track our errors but the app is crashing before it event gets to the setup of the connection to their service meaning we have no errors logs to help track the issue.

Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue or have any more info to help us track down the problem?

Comment: Since your app works fine after user reinstall it.I don't think it is the issue of your project . Maybe your app has crash in old version which will conflict with iOS 13.0 .

Comment: We had some similar problems on a small scale (only some devices were effected). There ended up being some code we need to change that worked pre-iOS 13 but Apple apparently became more strict with certain types of code in iOS 13 and caused some crashing. We debugged the code found and fixed the relevant code and are good to go now. Are you aware of what code is causing the crash by debugging?

Comment: e that worked pre-iOS 13 but Apple apparently became more strict with certain types of code in iOS 13. 
What did you have to change?